# Pandas groupby on basis of row values in one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have data in below format :

[image]

However I want to group by csv data on basis of sheet_internal_id such that I get the desired result:

[image]

I tried using below code :

df_1 = df.fillna('').groupby(['sheet_internal_id','nct_id'])['stat_design'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

but this is not giving the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for set values to empty strings:

```
m = df['Stat_design'].notna()
df.loc[m, 'stat_design'] = (df[m].groupby(['sheet_internal_id','NCT_ID'])['Stat_design']
                                 .transform(','.join))

df = df.mask(df.duplicated(['sheet_internal_id','NCT_ID']),'')
print (df)
   sheet_internal_id NCT_ID Stat_design         stat_design
0                  1  101.0    Superior            Superior
1                  1  102.0   Non-Infer  Non-Infer,Superior
2                                                          
3                  2  105.0        Othr                Othr
4                  3  106.0    Superior   Superior,Superior
5                                                          
6                  4  107.0       Other               Other
7                  5    NaN         NaN                 NaN
8                  6  110.0       Other               Other
9                  7  110.0   Non-Infer           Non-Infer
10                 7  111.0   Non-Infer  Non-Infer,Superior
11
```

Comment: it is still not working

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

It shows this error might be because of null values.